# Extracting properties from nested objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript, nested

This one may have been answered in the past, but I seem to be having trouble iterating through a nested structure and cannot find anything that will point me in the right direction. Below is the object I am trying to parse.

```
const nestedArray = 
  { id       : 100
  , interval : 1000
  , enable   : true
  , topics: 
    [ { topic1: 
        [ { id: 0, 'error-code' : 100 } 
        , { id: 1, status       : 200 } 
        , { id: 2, mode         : 300 } 
      ] } 
    , { topic2: 
        [ { id: 0, count     : 100 } 
        , { id: 1, total     : 200 } 
        , { id: 2, operation : 300 } 
  ] } ] }
```

I want to iterate `nestedArray` and from `topics` extract the the topic name i.e."topic1" and the key (name) in the associated key-value properties in the nested array i.e. "id" and "error-code".

I am new to this and have tried Object.entries, Object.keys, Object.values and a recursive function etc but never get the values I need or error because the method cant be applied to the Object. I would appreciate some explanation regarding how this is achieved.

Comment: what is your desired output? Just the topics array? Can you give an example of your expected output?

Comment: data structure in the question seems very confusing, why not update it to: 
`const nestedArray = 
  { id : 100 , interval : 1000, enable: true, 
topics: [ 
 { 
   keyname: 'topic1', 
   values: [ { id: 0, 'error-code' : 100 }, { id: 1, status: 200 } , { id: 2, 
   mode: 300 } ]
 } , 
{  
    keyname: 'topic2',  
    values: [{id:0, count:100 },{ id:1, total:200},{id:2,operation: 300 } ] 
  } 
 ]
}`

Comment: desired output is an array containing topic both keys [topic1, topic2] and and array containing al unique nested keys [id, error-code, status, mode, count, total, operation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that ?

```js
const nestedArray = 
  { id       : 100
  , interval : 1000
  , enable   : true
  , topics: 
    [ { topic1: 
        [ { id: 0, 'error-code' : 100 } 
        , { id: 1, status       : 200 } 
        , { id: 2, mode         : 300 } 
      ] } 
    , { topic2: 
        [ { id: 0, count     : 100 } 
        , { id: 1, total     : 200 } 
        , { id: 2, operation : 300 } 
  ] } ] }

nestedArray.topics.forEach( topic =>
  {
  let key0 = Object.keys( topic)[0]
  topic[key0].forEach(el =>
    console.log( key0, '->', Object.keys(el). join(', ')))
  })

console.log( '\notherwise :')

nestedArray.topics.forEach( topic =>
  {
  let key0 = Object.keys( topic)[0]
  topic[key0].forEach(el =>
    console.log( key0, '->', Object.entries(el).map(([k,v])=>`${k}: ${v} `).join(', ')))
  })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
.as-console-row::after { display:none !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a closer look at your solution